# QT - Writing data input to csv with QTextStream

Tags: c++, qt, csv

I have data coming in from an Arduino, which I want to write to a CSV file. The problem is the data keeps overwriting the existing line. Here's a sample of the code:

```
QFile data("F:/logdata.csv");


if (data.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate)) {
 QTextStream out(&data);



 out << hum << "," << temp << "," << gas << '\n';


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening the file, use "QIODevice::Append" flag, so the data you write to it will be appended at the end of the file.

Example:

```
data.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate |QIODevice::Append)
```

Comment: I tried putting in this line: if (data.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate | QFile::Append)) but it didn't do any difference.

Comment: Try QIODevice::Append

Comment: (QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate | QIODevice::Append) like this? It still overwrite the existing line

Comment: Remove the truncate flag.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to reopen and append data to the same file? In that case you don't want to use the `QFile::Truncate` flag since it will remove the content in that file.

Please see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html:

> **QIODevice::Truncate** If possible, the device is truncated before it is opened. All earlier
>   contents of the device are lost.

Also as suggested by Ibarros use the `QIODevice::Append` flag to make sure data is appended.

**Update**

Actually you also don't want to use the `QIODevice::WriteOnly` flag too, since it will add the truncate flag. You should use `QIODevice::ReadWrite` instead.

```
data.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite| QIODevice::Append)
```